# Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <DGTabBarController: 0xd15e2e0>

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa

I have following code in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`

```
_tabBarController = [ [ DGTabBarController alloc ] init ];
_tabBarController.viewControllers = @[library, Login];

self.window.rootViewController = _tabBarController;
[_tabBarController presentCreationViewControllerWithYarn:nil];
```

and in DGTabBarController.m

```
- (void)presentCreationViewControllerWithYarn:(DGYarn*)yarn;
{
    DGPagesViewController *createPagesViewController = [[DGPagesViewController alloc] initWithYarn:yarn];
    [self presentViewController:createPagesViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

On every start I receive a warning in debug log "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for ."

How this could be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to start presenting animation when application is not ready yet. Try to change

```
[_tabBarController presentCreationViewControllerWithYarn:nil];
```

to

```
[_tabBarController performSelector:@selector(presentCreationViewControllerWithYarn:) withObject:0 afterDelay:0.01];
```